# Custom authorization in MVC4 and Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I'm being confused by the custom authorization in MVC4. 
I have implemented a custom security attribute (based on System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute) that worked fine and now I started to extend my project with a web api. However, it seems that the web api needs to use the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute (?).

Can't I use the same authorization for both web api and standard mvc pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said: no you cannot. The systems were made seperatly. It might be possible that Microsoft will merge these in the future.

Comment: Wow, that seems incredibly stupid.. So I actually have to create two almost identical classes, and manually make sure that developers don't apply the wrong type of authorize attribute to the different actions?

Comment: Well yes, personally i like to put the classes in the same file with a name like: `MVCAuthorizationAttribute` and `APIAuthorizationAttribute` to prevent developers using the wrong one but it's your call. I actually tried to make a generic attribute which would direct to the correct one (it would check what type of controller it was), but this isn't possible without giving a parameter or something.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the way to do it... 
I must say that since Microsoft launched MVC, I've always been impressed with their new components and frameworks, but this one was a bit of a disappointment.